# Is it possible in Google Sheets to call a URL with the client's IP

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need users to receive a response from a certain server based on the token they type, but if many incorrect responses are sent to it, the server blocks the IP address that sent the wrong token
Since I don't want the Google Script server to be blocked, is there a possibility to make the client send the request through his private IP?

Right now what I'm doing is a decidedly inelegant form
I ask the client to enter the link and enter the response to `SpreadsheetApp.getUi().prompt();`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description I would assume that in order to receive a response from the server the URL fetch service is being used, if so, the [API documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch#:%7E:text=Requests%20made%20using%20this%20service%20originate%20from%20a%20set%20pool%20of%20IP%20ranges) states that the requests will always come from a specific set of IPs, this means that from Apps Script backend this is not possible but there is a workaround but it requires to

1. Create a Sidebar
2. Run a fetch() function (This runs in AJAX so it runs in the client's side)

The result will look something like this:

[image: Example]

The HTML file is called index in this example and it looks like this:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
      </head>
      <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="fetching()"value="clickme"></input>
        </br>
        <div id="field"></div>
        <script>
        function fetching(){
        fetch('https://httpbin.org/anything')
        .then(response => response.json()) 
        //.then(json => console.log(json))
        .then(json => document.getElementById("field").innerHTML= "Response: "+JSON.stringify(json.origin))
         }
      </script>
      </body>
      
    
    </html>
```

And the code file looks like this:

```
    function onOpen() {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
          .createMenu('Custom Menu')
          .addItem('Show sidebar', 'showSidebar')
          .addToUi();
    }
    
    function showSidebar() {
      var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index.html')
          .setTitle('My custom sidebar');
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
          .showSidebar(html);
    }
```

You could also copy [this Google sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fyOLGQT8ax-8-FGrmKNA6g6kLdnoYyhZB1aE05om3Bc/edit?usp=sharing) to have a working example that you can use as a base, please keep in mind that the code is a GET request and is only meant to illustrate the way this works, it seems like what you would need is a POST request, to do that you can use [this guide](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-fetch-api-tutorial-with-js-fetch-post-and-header-examples/#:%7E:text=Passing%20Data%20to%20a%20POST%20Request)

Hope this helps!

Comment: But I need to get the data back to the script